# What is the fastest way to get images from external webpage?

Tags: php

I need a way to get the biggest 5 images from a generic external webpage.

I know that I can't do this with only ajax ( maybe I am wrong ) due cross-site security.

So I must use php+javascript.

I have just written this PHP code to get all images from external url:

```
$html = file_get_contents($link);
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
  echo $image->getAttribute('src');
}
```

So now what is the fastest way to get only the biggest 5 images of that page ?

With biggest I mean images with highest resolutions.

Comment: If you pull the images from server-side code, you should at least cache them and then serve them.  You could also just get the SRC of the remove image, compile the absolute path `http://server.com/path/to/image` for example, and then just do `<img src="<?php echo $remoteImg ?>">` so that the browser downloads the images and not the server, then from the server to the browser.. This would be the fastest way IMO.

Comment: please clarify **biggest** in this context, big in a sense of dimension or file size?

Comment: with biggest I mean images with highest resolutions.

Comment: Mhh. That could be the smallest in size..

Comment: Get a faster network connection.

Comment: I mean images with biggest ( width x height )

Comment: and of course you haver permission from "generic external webpage"

Comment: permission is not needed

Comment: @Dagon Permission is implied by the server making the images publicly available. The dimensions of an image are not subject to any copyright laws.

Comment: lol thats so deluded.

Comment: @Dagon So tell me; someone makes data publicly available, but objects when someone actually accesses this data? This seems schizophrenic to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "biggest" as in in largest file size, then I think you are somehwat on the right track already.  You would just need to find all the images in the source document, then likely make a HEAD request to the server where the image lies to (hopefully) get the file size information from the headers without downloading the file.

If "fastest" really is your concern, you could use cURL which has "multi" support for making parallel requests. Once you get the header information from the requests, you can determine the 5 biggest files and display the URL to them.

If the URL you are calling doesn't change much, you could probably cache the results locally to prevent the need to parse through the page and/or make HEAD requests on the images.

If "biggest" as in largest image size, then you are likely going to need to inspect the images on your server using an image library.

Comment: with biggest I mean images with highest resolutions.

Comment: @xRobot Highest resolution meaning highest total pixel count or highest pixel density?  I guess either way the point is moot in that you will need to use an image library to derive that information, as you won;t get it from the web server headers.

Comment: highest total pixel count :)

Answer (score 0):

> What is the fastest way to get images from external webpage?

With any method that you use, the network connection is by far your limiting factor. It makes no sense to optimize.

> I need a way to get the biggest 5 images from a generic external webpage.

A HTTP HEAD request should give you information about how many bytes need to be transfered to download the image. The response to a HEAD request should be the HTTP header, that would have been sent if it where a GET request. Especially the HTTP body (which contains the actual image data) is omitted. Notice the word *should* instead of the (IMHO more preferable) word *must*.

Furthermore, the number of bytes is not an adequate measure for the number of pixels in the image. You might employ some heuristics based on the contant type (PNG has a different size than GIF has a different size than JPEG for the same number of pixels). I don't know if this is accurate enough for you. For example JPEG images can vary widely due to different compression levels.

Comment: With biggest I mean images with more pixels in the image.

Comment: Then you need to download them all. Or apply some heuristic based on image format and byte size, that might give you an adequate, but not optimal, solution.